# How do I make the right click context menu always appear below the mouse like macOS?

Tags: gnome, gui, gtk, window, context-menu

On macOS, if your cursor is near the bottom of the screen, the context menu appears below your cursor, but offset by the bottom of the screen, like this: [image: macOS context menu]. However, on Ubuntu, the menu opens above the cursor when there isn't enough space for it below. How can I make context menus function like macOS in this regard?